# A shortcut for Merge all Windows on macOS Sierra

Tags: finder, automator, macos, tabs

Are there any shortcut for the command merge all windows feature that comes with macOS Sierra? I did not encounter about an shortcut for this command and I did not see any property in Automator app. If is it possible, it will be nice improvement for productivity when we working with tabs rather than windows.

Comment: Merge all windows in what application?

Comment: any app that supports merge all windows feature like safari, finder, maps, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Open **** → **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **App Shortcuts**.
2. Click the `+` to add a new shortcut.
3. Choose *All Applications* from the **Application** dropdown.
4. As the **Menu Title**, enter *Merge All Windows* (*see note at the bottom).
5. Input a key combination of your choice as the **Keyboard Shortcut**. I use <kbd>Ctrl ^</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>.

Now all applications with a menu item called **Merge All Windows** will respond to that key combination, and collapse all your windows into one.

Starting with Sierra, it is also possible to open documents in new tabs rather than in new windows. This is enabled by going into **** → **System Preferences** → **Dock** and setting **Prefer tabs when opening documents** to *Always*.

If you would like new Terminal sessions to open as new tabs as well, you can achieve this by placing a file named `.bashrc` in `~` (your `Home` folder), with the following line in it:

`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Merge All Windows" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1 of process "Terminal"' >/dev/null 2>&1`

**Note**: *Merge All Windows* may differ based on your operating system's language. If you are not using the *English (US)* locale, open **Finder**, and click the **Window** menu to determine the name of that command in your locale.

Comment: Thanks, it's very good approach. Could you note that 'Merge All Windows' defined as system's default language?

Comment: Not necessarily, @mathema. For example, my system's default locale is Russian, and obviously I have to have a shortcut for «Объединить все окна» (literally “Merge all windows”) menu item, but in apps like Sublime Text or Sublime Merge it's still in English — “Merge All Windows”. So I have two identical shortcuts (both Ctrl+W) with different menu items, works like a charm :)

Comment: Great answer. Now I want to find a way to ALWAYS open new finder (or better - everything) as a tab. When working a lot on my Mac I find it hard to navigate dozens of windows, especially in dark mode.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me just fine for Safari and Finder:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            click menu item "Merge All Windows" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Let me know if this solves your issue.

edit:
This script works for any active app that supports "Merge all windows":

```
try
    tell application "System Events" to tell (first process where it is frontmost) to click menu item "Merge All Windows" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1
end try
```

Comment: it solves mostly thanks but I must implement this feature every app that support this feature. Can I specify tell applicaion "Safari" or "Evernote" or "Maps" for supporting all apps with single shortcut? Otherwise, I must create different shortcuts for every Automator script for supporting different apps.

Comment: I've added a universal script to my answer.

Comment: Well, let's go a step further. When I open a new tab, is this script can be trigger the merge all windows automatically?

Comment: I'm glad that it works for you. Regarding the tabs: Unfortunately that's not possible.

Comment: Elegant. Very nice